# find and replace directories in linux

Tags: linux

I’m new to Linux and I’ve been searching on how to find and replace directories. Basically I have a path in an `.xml` file that looks like:

```
/some/directory/path
```

And I want to change that to some other directory like:

```
/some/other/path
```

But for the life of me I can’t find a simple tutorial on how to do something like this.

Comment: You need to read up on regular expressions. You can either use a GUI editor like `medit` with RE built in, or you can use `sed` in a script. Provided there are no ambiguities, you might even get away with a simple substitution without RE. There are plenty of tutorials around: just search for **linux medit tutorial** or **linux sed tutorial**. Because of shell syntax a script can appear more complex, but is preferable if you are going to perform the substitution repeatedly on different files.

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you running? (i.e. Ubuntu)
Is it a one-off task or would you need to apply this on multiple files/times?
Have you ever written a program in any language? (This is just to know what level of answer you would require.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed:

```
sed 's/\/some\/directory\/path/\/some\/other\/path/ig' file.xml > file2.xml
```

The format of the regular expression part is:

```
sed 's/original_text/replacement_text/ig'
```

You'll need to escape any spaces and backslashes in the folder path.

The /i part of "ig" means to ignore case, and the /g part means to replace all instances where it finds the original_text.